# What kind of strings does this regex match?

Tags: regex

Please give me examples of text which match this regex:

```
root/(.+)-go-to-products.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will match anything that contains with "root/", followed by something, followed by "-go-to-products", followed by a character, followed by "php".

```
root/a-go-to-products.php //Okay
root/a-go-to-products.ph  //Not okay
a-go-to-products.phproot/ //Not okay
root/-go-to-products.php  //Not okay
root/a-go-to-products php //Okay
```

You might want to escape the last `.` for it to capture only the dot character.

```
root/(.+)-go-to-products\.php
```

---

**Resources :**

- [regular-expressions.info - The dot matcher](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- [regular-expressions.info - Repetition with start and plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [regular-expressions.info - Literal Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Answer (score 5):

It matches any string that has `root/` followed by one ore more characters other than newline followed by `-go-to-products` followed by any one char(other than newline) followed by `php` and these can occur **anywhere** in the string.

It'll match:

```
root/f-go-to-products.php
root/foo-go-to-products.php
root/foo-go-to-products.php5     # Because you are not using anchor
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905066?root/f-go-to-products.php # no anchor
root/../foo-go-to-products.php   # . can match a literal . and /
```

and also

```
root/foo-go-to-products-php      # because . is a meta char.
```

But not

```
root/-go-to-products.php         # because .+ expects at least 1 char.
```

To match the `.` before `php` literally escape it as: `root/(.+)-go-to-products\.php`

Also if you are using the regex just for matching and you don't want to extract what is matched by `.+` you can drop the parenthesis and just use:

`root/.+-go-to-products\.php`

To ensure a match does not happen when the pattern is found as a substring you should anchors as: `^root/.+-go-to-products\.php$`

Since a `.` matches a literal `.` and a `/`, your regex can match potentially dangerous inputs like: `root/../bar/foo-go-to-products.php`. In this input the php file `foo-go-to-products.php` is not present in the `root` directory but is present in the `root/../bar` directory which is `bar` directory at the same level as `root`.

Comment: Nice catch about `products-php`. I'd add `root/foo/~bar/../../../baz-go-to-products.php` as well, to show that all kinds of other potentially dangerous stuff gets accepted.

Comment: You can make any url match that regex: `anypage.php?dummy=root/f-go-to-products.php`

Comment: @Kobi even with anchors it can fail: `root/index.php?dummy=-go-to-products.php`